# (Beginner Java) class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java

Forgive me for posting a question very similar to one that I posted last night.  I've simplified the problem in order to ask something more specific:

I'm getting a (class, interface, or enum expected) error when I use the following code:

```
import java.util.*;


ArrayList<egg> eggys = new ArrayList<egg>;


public class EggTest{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        egg a = new egg();
        egg b = new egg();

        eggys.add(a);
        eggys.add(b);

        for (egg eggo :eggys){
            System.out.println(eggo.size);
        }
    }
}
```

The output from the compiler is:

```
eggys.java:4: class, interface, or enum expected
ArrayList<egg> eggys = new ArrayList<egg>;
^
1 error
```

I'm not doing something right.  Can anyone help me figure out how to use ArrayList?

Comment: Please consider naming classes with UpperCasedFirstLetter. It's convention

Comment: In simpler terms: you can give a variable a starting value like "int i = 1" at the top of the class before the methods, but not if it uses "new".  So "foo bar = new foo()", that has to go inside a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is a purely object oriented langauage, which means any/all the properties should belong to an entity i.e  class/interface/enums. In your case you have defined a property/variable as mentioned below, which does not belong to either a class/enum/interface and hence java compiler complains for it.

```
ArrayList<egg> eggys = new ArrayList<egg>;
```

You cannot have this property like global variables in other programming languages. Java's purely object oriented nature does not allow so.

Also as mentioned by "skiwi" in comment below, you have syntax error in your ArrayList definition as well. You are missing the parentheses towards the end. It should be corrected to:

```
ArrayList<egg> eggys = new ArrayList<egg>();
```

Comment: It should be `ArrayList<Egg> eggys = new ArrayList<Egg>();` though. The OP didn't stick to the naming convention and worse, made a syntactical error in the decleration.

Comment: @skiwi Yeah i overlooked his syntax error as i tried to focus on the understanding of language. Anyways thanks let me put it in resolution.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've got it now!  I'll pick an answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 6):

You can only declare variables inside a class or method; not as top-level code.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other languages such as C or C++, you cannot put variables or other declarations outside of a class or a function:

```
public class EggTest{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        egg a = new egg();
        egg b = new egg();
        List<egg> eggys = new ArrayList<egg>();
        eggys.add(a);
        eggys.add(b);

        for (egg eggo :eggys){
            System.out.println(eggo.size);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, a local variable looks like a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Put this line inside the class

   `ArrayList<egg> eggys = new ArrayList<egg>;`
2. You are missing () in the above line. It should be:

   `ArrayList<egg> eggys = new ArrayList<egg>();`

Answer (score 0):

do this as follows.

```
import java.util.*;

public class EggTest{
ArrayList<egg> eggys = new ArrayList<egg>();
    public static void main(String [] args){

        egg a = new egg();
        egg b = new egg();

        eggys.add(a);
        eggys.add(b);

        for (egg eggo :eggys){
            System.out.println(eggo.size);
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
import java.util.*;

public class EggTest{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayList<egg> eggys = new ArrayList<egg>();
        egg a = new egg();
        egg b = new egg();

        eggys.add(a);
        eggys.add(b);

        for (egg eggo :eggys){
            System.out.println(eggo.size);
        }
    }
}
```

Second method can only be used if you are accessing `ArrayList` variable only inside your main method.

The error you are getting is just because you are trying to declare your `ArrayList` variable as a top level declaration. variables in java can only be declared inside a class
 or a method.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what *eggys* list is doing above the class. In Java, you can't declare variables above to a normal class.