# ERROR"class,interface or enum expected"

Tags: java

I want to know that what does the error " class,interface or enum expected" means and how to resolve this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887093/beginner-java-class-interface-or-enum-expected

Comment: Post your source code, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The error can be anything.. provide your code . Even ending braces can be the error

Comment: have you declared your variables and methods inside a class and not in the outer space!!!

Comment: Error comes in  if (encoder.parseArgs(args)) {
      encoder.encode();

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a method that isn't in a class. Methods or functions can only be declared in classes. you can post your code so I can have a clear idea on the error.

Update:

you should remove parentheses near the class name declaration it should be

like this

`public class JSpeexEnc{ }`

insted of this

```
public class JSpeexEnc(){ }
```

Comment: public class JSpeexEnc(){
 
   
    public static void main( String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
    JSpeexEnc encoder = new JSpeexEnc();
    if (encoder.parseArgs(args)) {
      encoder.encode();
    }
      
    }
 } This is my part of code where i am getting this error.

Comment: you should remove parentheses near the class name declaration
it should be like this
public class JSpeexEnc{

}

insted of this 

public class JSpeexEnc(){

}

Comment: removed...still error exisits

Answer (score 0):

You propably have something like this

```
public MyClass{
}
```

and you need something like this

```
public class MyClass{
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but not working...

Comment: public class JSpeexEnc(){
 
   
    public static void main( String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
    JSpeexEnc encoder = new JSpeexEnc();
    if (encoder.parseArgs(args)) {
      encoder.encode();
    }
      
    }
 } This is my part of code in which I am getting an error

Comment: Error comes in  if (encoder.parseArgs(args)) {
      encoder.encode();